# Azure Face API not working with local file

Tags: java, azure, face-api

I've been trying to send an image from my computer to this API but I only get the following error: `{"error":{"code":"InvalidImageSize","message":"Image size is too small."}}`

My code is the following.
I have a PostRequestClass with this method:

```
public void sendImageRequest(String imagePath) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        File file = new File(imagePath);
        FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        reqEntity.setChunked(false);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            this.responseResult = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

And on my Main is this one:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        PostRequest p = new PostRequest(
          "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceAttributes=emotion"
        );
        p.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        p.addHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "my-api-key");
        p.sendImageRequest("/Users/user/Desktop/image.jpg");
        System.out.println(p.getResponseResult());           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the following code:

```
public void sendImageRequest(String imagePath) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        File file = new File(imagePath);
        FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);            
        ByteArrayEntity reqEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(bytes, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        request.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            this.responseResult = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/ and click "API reference".
2. It will take you to Face API reference page https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236

The Face API documenatation says "JPEG, PNG, GIF (the first frame), and BMP format are supported. The allowed image file size is from 1KB to 4MB."

Under the heading "Error code and message returned in JSON",
it says, "InValidImageSize" means "The valid image file size should be larger than or equal to 1KB."

Comment: Thanks, I tried my solution below and it worked. I think that I was not sending the request in a correct way.